# Inherit from multiple classes

Tags: c#

How can I make 2 classes inherit from a single base class? I thought...

```
class Attributes : Student, Teacher
{
 // insert code here 
}
```

..would work, but doesn't. Any help?

Comment: Making two classes inherit from the same base is different from having a class inherit two different classes.  Which one are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

There is no multiple inheritance in C#. You have to use composition and, optionally, interface inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to *"make 2 classes inherit from a single base class"* and your base class is `Attributes`, then:

```
public class Student : Attributes 
{
    // insert code here 
}

public class Teacher : Attributes
{
    // insert code here 
}
```

Multiple inheritance instead is not supported in C#.

[Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_inheritance.htm) some basics about inheritance in C#

Answer (score 0):

C# does not support inheriting from multiple classes. In fact any fully object-oriented language like java also does not support multiple inheritance. The reason is, multiple inheritance leads to the diamond problem. 
[image]

To avoid the problem, fully OO provide support for multiple interface inheritance.

```
public interface IStudent

public interface ITeacher
class Attributes :IStudent, ITeacher
```

One another way as others have pointed out is to use composition.

```
class student{}
class Teacher{}

Class Attributes
{
     private Teacher teacher;
     private Student student;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a source on how multiple inheritance makes a language not "pure OO"?

Comment: @phant0m: I see what you are saying. Java and C# are called fully OO languages and not pure OO because they support primitive types.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple responses:

1. c# java and the likes don't allow multiple inheritance.
2. But you can implement multiple interfaces.
3. the other thing is you
   should not really need multiple inheritance.

I suggest you take a look at what you really need. as others pointed out composition or multiple interface implementation may be the answer.

Also, your question is confusing. The code sample shows a class (`Attribute`) inheriting two super classes (`Teacher`, `Student`). But the description asks whether you can do:

```
class Teacher : Attribute
{ }
```

and

```
class Student : Attribute
{ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about what is common between `Student` and `Teacher` and put it in an interface

```
public interface IAttributes
{
    public string Name { get; }
}

public class Student : IAttributes
{
}
public class Teacher : IAttributes
{
}
```

Alternatively you can encapsulate

```
public class Attributes 
{ 
     public Student Student { get; }
     public Teacher Teacher { get; }
}
```

which is a completely different model than the first one.